# Oauth1.0 third party api integration not working for post method

Tags: php

I am working on third party api integration using oauth1.0 in php.
all get methods working but only post method api not working giving oauth verification failed.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://samplewebsite.com/generatebill",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n\"availableTripId\": \"2000002130750088374\",\r\n\"boardingPointId\": \"220692\",\r\n\"droppingPointId\": \"208070\",\r\n\"destination\": \"3\",\r\n\"inventoryItems\": [{\r\n\"fare\": \"105.00\",\r\n\"ladiesSeat\": \"false\",\r\n\"passenger\": {\r\n\"address\": \"S.K.C ROAD\",\r\n\"age\": \"34\",\r\n\"email\": \"univerttt@gmail.com\",\r\n\"gender\": \"MALE\",\r\n\"mobile\": \"9933336069\",\r\n\"name\": \"PRAKASH RAO \",\r\n\"primary\": \"true\",\r\n\"title\": \"Mr\"\r\n},\r\n\"seatName\": \"2\"\r\n}],\r\n\"source\": \"102\"\r\n}",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1', oauth_signature='6NzsraQZ0GcfEKxcOXYP4fRqZxQ%3D', oauth_nonce='5cf2603501283', '
    . 'oauth_timestamp='1559388213',  oauth_consumer_key='xxxxxxxxxx', oauth_version='1.0','Content-Type: application/json'"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

if let me know there is any good library for oauth1.0 and what is problem in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use `json_encode()` function instead of manually adding JSON string in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` parameter. Sometimes manually adding string, we missed comma, quote or double quote matching.

```
$arrParams = [
    'availableTripId' => '2000002130750088374',
    'boardingPointId' => '220692',
    'droppingPointId' => '208070',
    ...
];
$postParams = json_encode($arrParams);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    ...
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postParams,
    ...
));
```

Hope it may helpful to you!